# Combination, Subset, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinations

I use `combnk` to generate a list of combinations. But, the result shape is not my required data. I want for example for `combnk(1:3,2)`:

```
1 1 0  
0 1 1
1 0 1
```

not

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

How can i do it? How can i change the `combnk` in optimal way to give results?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean you want

```
1 1 0 
1 0 1 
0 1 1
```

instead of

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

So that each row is a logical selection vector for the original vector `v`?

You can get this with the following:

```
v = 1:3;
k = 2;

tmp = combnk(v,k);
M = size(tmp,1);

output = false(M,numel(v));
output(sub2ind(size(output),repmat((1:M)',1,k),tmp))=true;
```

result:

```
output =

     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
c = combnk(1:3,2);
r = repmat(1:size(c,1), [1 size(c,2)]);
output = full(sparse(r,c(:),1))
```

result:

```
output =
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     1     1
```